# Ionic not running on windows after installing a fresh copy of everything(node, npm, cordova, ionic)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been facing problem in running ionic commands and getting the following error : -

```
fs.js:794
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir     'C:\Users\user;C:\Users\Admin\
.ssh\.ionic'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:794:18)
    at new IonicStore      (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\store.js:20:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:6:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

I have tried to install the fresh copy of node, npm cordova and ionic but still getting the same error. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you please post the code that cause the problem

Comment: I have just wrote     ionic in the command prompt.

Comment: Maybe this should be on super user rather than SO.  Have you had a look for the answer there?